# How to click buttons in an application using AutoIt or Windows UI Automation

Tags: vb.net, ui-automation, autoit

**Setup Environment:**

I'm using vb.net to develop a Windows Form Application with .NET Framework 4.

**My goal:**

1. Open *calculator.exe* using `Process.Start`
2. Using all vb.net code, be able to click `5 + 5 =`

I do not want to use SendKeys as a method.

**After researching, this link provided a good start:**

This tutorial (written in C#) is very similar to what I'm trying to do by using vb.net:

- [How to click a button in another application](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SamTomato/clicking-a-button-in-another-application/)

Could somebody provide a pointer on how to go about approaching this? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You are trying too hard. Simply use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead. Added bonus: Using UI Automation (properly) will not fail on non-english versions of Windows (like your proposed solution).

Comment: A window class and a control ID are unrelated, so your `FindWindowEx` call with `00000079` makes no sense. I may answer with explanations on how to get the `=` button, but I bet you don't want to target calc.exe in your final code. In what kind of external application do you want to click?

Comment: Instead of clicking the =, how about just using `SendKeys` to send the `ENTER` key?

Comment: A lot of Microsoft programs have DLL files you can reference in your project to run their functions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**My Solution:**

I tried two approaches:

- [Windows UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163288.aspx)
- [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/)

AutoIt was what I used because it was more reliable for my specific application.

However, Windows UI worked as well.    Here are both solutions.

**Steps if using Windows UI Automation**:

- Identify Control IDs of buttons using Spy++
- Add references to `UIAutomationClient` and `UIAutomationTypes`
- Set `aeDesktop` as the root ae element and invoke button clicks

[image: WindowsUI References]

```
Imports System.Windows.Automation
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class Form1

    Private aeDesktop As AutomationElement
    Private aeCalculator As AutomationElement

    Private ae5Btn As AutomationElement
    Private aeAddBtn As AutomationElement
    Private aeEqualsBtn As AutomationElement

    Private p As Process

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try

            'Set reference to the root ae element - the desktop
            aeDesktop = AutomationElement.RootElement

            'Launch Calculator application 
            p = Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe")

            '**********  Keep looping while waiting to get the reference to the "Calculator" on Desktop ************************************

            Dim numwaits As Integer = 0

            Do
                Debug.WriteLine("Looking for Calculator . . . ")
                aeCalculator = aeDesktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Calculator"))
                numwaits += 1
                Thread.Sleep(100)

            Loop While aeCalculator Is Nothing AndAlso numwaits < 50

            If aeCalculator Is Nothing Then
                Throw New Exception("Failed to find Calculator")
            Else
                Debug.WriteLine("Found the Calculator Application!")
            End If

            '*********************************************************************************************************************************


            'NOTE: In spy++ Controlids are represented as hex (i.e. 00000087) - need to convert these to decimal (i.e. 135)

            '`5` btn
            '00000087 ---> 135
            Dim btn5hexID As String = "00000087"
            Dim btn5decimalID As String = Convert.ToInt32("00000087", 16).ToString

            '`+` btn
            '0000005D ---> 93
            Dim btnAddhexID As String = "0000005D"
            Dim btnAdddecimalID As String = Convert.ToInt32("0000005D", 16).ToString

            '`=` btn
            '00000079 ---> 121
            Dim btnEqualshexID As String = "00000079"
            Dim btnEqualsdecimalID As String = Convert.ToInt32("00000079", 16).ToString


            'Set reference for the `5` Button
            ae5Btn = aeCalculator.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, btn5decimalID))

            'Set reference for the `+` Button
            aeAddBtn = aeCalculator.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, btnAdddecimalID))

            'Set reference for the `=` Button
            aeEqualsBtn = aeCalculator.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, btnEqualsdecimalID))


            'Manipulate calculator application by using invoke method to click on buttons
            Dim ipClick5Btn As InvokePattern = DirectCast(ae5Btn.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern), InvokePattern)
            Dim ipClickAddBtn As InvokePattern = DirectCast(aeAddBtn.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern), InvokePattern)
            Dim ipClickEqualsBtn As InvokePattern = DirectCast(aeEqualsBtn.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern), InvokePattern)

            'Click 5
            ipClick5Btn.Invoke()

            'Click +
            ipClickAddBtn.Invoke()

            'Click 5
            ipClick5Btn.Invoke()

            'Click =
            ipClickEqualsBtn.Invoke()

            'Now calculator should display 10 as a result


            'Wait two seconds before closing
            Thread.Sleep(2000)

            'Exit Calculator
            p.CloseMainWindow()



        Catch ex As Exception

            'Handle any exceptions
            Debug.WriteLine("Fatal error: " & ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

**Steps if using AutoIt**:

- Identify ClassnameNN of buttons
- Get a handle for calc.exe
- Use [ControlClick](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/controls.htm) function to click buttons

[image: Finder Tool]

If using AutoIt choose the full installation and download the Script Editor.  Paste the code in and it should work.

- [Download AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/)

```
;Open up Calculator
Run('calc.exe')

;Pause execution until Calculator becomes active window
WinWaitActive('Calculator')

;Get the handle for Calculator
$hWnd = WinGetHandle('Calculator')

;Using the `Finder Tool`, you can drag and drop it onto controls to see all information (i.e. Text, Class, Handle, etc.)

;`ClassnameNN: Button10` is the number 5
;`ClassnameNN: Button23` is the addition operator (+)
;`ClassnameNN: Button28` is the equals operator (=)

;***** simple operation will perform 5 + 5 = 10 **************

;click 5
ControlClick($hWnd, "", "[CLASSNN:Button10]")

;click +
ControlClick($hWnd, "", "[CLASSNN:Button23]")

;click 5
ControlClick($hWnd, "", "[CLASSNN:Button10]")

;click =
ControlClick($hWnd, "", "[CLASSNN:Button28]")

;calculator should now display 10 as a result

;************************************************************

;Wait 2 seconds to show result
Sleep(2000)

;Close Calculator
WinClose($hWnd)

Exit
```

Thank you for all the help and suggestions in the comments.  It helped tremendously.